# The code is for downloading excel file(.xls)

Tags: php

Problem:
 After download, the file doesn't contain the data.
 i.e it become blank.

So please help me for this.

```
<?php

    session_start();
    include_once 'oesdb.php';
    $id=$_REQUEST['id'];

    if(isset($_REQUEST['id']))
    {
      $sql=executeQuery("SELECT * FROM file where id=$id");
      $rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
      $file =$rows['file'];


          header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
          header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
          header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
          header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
          header('Expires: 0');
          header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
          header('Pragma: public');
          header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
          ob_clean();
          flush();
          readfile('uploads/'.$file);
          exit;

     }
?>
```

Comment: Does the file 'uploads/'.$file exist? What's the return code of readfile() function?

Comment: By the way, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attack, fix that.

Comment: you are using `filesize($file)` and `readfile('uploads/'.$file)`, so pls check where is the `$file` is, doea the variable `$file` contain `uploads/`?

Comment: I have created a Folder named UPLOAD. All files are saved in it.

Comment: @ChiragSoni if is it solved ? if solved then please post answer

Answer (score 2):

Why not create a HTACCESS file in uploads folder then states

```
    Allow From 127.0.0.1
    Deny From All
```

Then just create a URL, use HTML5's new download feature, do something like this:

```
    <a href="uploads/filenamehere.txt" download="filenamehere.txt">click to download</a>
```

It saves time trying to use PHP to make a download script.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing this:

```
$file =$rows['file'];
```

by this:

```
$file = "uploads/".$rows['file'];
```

and this:

```
readfile('uploads/'.$file);
```

by this

```
readfile($file);
```

if still not working put the value returned by the `readfile` function

**IMPORTANT**

Please take in consideration the sql injection issues (see comment of Ondřej Mirtes)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
```

`Content-Length` receives zero value and browser downloads zero-length file, as you told him. If `$file` is path relative to `upload/`, you should do this:

```
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('upload/'.$file));
```

Be sure that `filezise()` returns correct size and `readfile()` realy outputs it.

But the other problem is that you mentioned `UPLOAD` folder and using `uploads`. They are not same and case is important. Also, may be using relative paths in `'uploads/'.$file` is not a good idea, it is better to use absolute path. For example, `'/var/www/upload/'.$file`.