# excel file not downloading in proper format in php

Tags: php, html, excel

I have use following code for download excel file.

```
$filename = "property.xls"; // File Name
// Download file
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

But, it will download blank excel file i need to download content of `<table>` tag.

I have place this code at top of page and during reloading of my page it will download excel file but it was empty every time.

Comment: its core php or PHPExcel?

Comment: ok,try this header,
header("Content-Length: ".filesize("property.xls"));

Comment: because you never set content size. The empty Content-Length header is being treated as a zero length, so you get an empty file.

Comment: @VasimVanzara not working it download file with error "filesize() [function.filesize]:stat failed for property.xls in"

Comment: you have to add content-length header with file size constant

Comment: @SmitSaraiya are you generating xls file or it already has contents in it?

Comment: @ravisachaniya no this will download xls file with contents which are on my entire page

Comment: @SmitSaraiya make sure your are reading file after `headers` using `readfile` or other method, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913646/the-code-is-for-downloading-excel-file-xls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per last comment by @ravisachaniya i have removed `<head>` and `<title>` tag and all default content which comes when we create page, from current page and from connection page, Now it is works properly